# Multiple item carousel not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I have tried multiple items carousels like owl carousel, slick carousel, swiper but nothing is working in angular6. I have installed all modules properly and added dependencies. Initially I thought jQuery is not working but when I write simple jQuery code its executing properly but carousels not working.

This is the output I am getting for that owl carousel:

[image: This is the output I am getting for that owl carousel]

https://medium.com/@biswa8998/owl-carousel-with-angular-6-banner-slider-and-image-carousel-3b3ded0070c5

followed all instructions given here

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didnot link the right path. please check it out. If you fail i will provide you the full code that works for my project.
https://github.com/vitalii-andriiovskyi/ngx-owl-carousel-o#readme

Comment: Thank you for reply Irin. But this carousel is not working in my project but if i implement it separately its working fine. I thought some other module is effecting that module.